# listview-SQLite updating the wrong row

Tags: android

When I update the selected row it updates the wrong row for example if I select second row, it will update the first row.

Here is my code inside db controller

```
Public boolean updateContact (String id, String category, String code, String description, String unit, String quantity) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_2 , category);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_3 , code);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_4 , description);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_5 , unit);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_6 , quantity);
    // updating row
     database.update(TABLE_NAME  ,values , FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_1 + " = ?" , new String[]{id} );
    return true;

}
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllProducts() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> proList;
    proList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Countsheet";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("Category", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("Code", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("Description", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("Unit", cursor.getString(4));
            map.put("Quantity", cursor.getString(5));
            proList.add(map);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();

    }

    return proList;

}
```

Here is my button onclick to update the listview:

```
Public void adddata(){
        btnadddata.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean i =  myDb.updateContact(passid ,  passedVar , passcode, passdesc, passunit ,  quantitys.getText().toString());

                            if (i == true)
                                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this , "Data Inserted" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this , "Data Not Inserted" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: From where do you get `passid`?

Comment: Try this database.update(TABLE_NAME  ,values , FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.Col_1 + "=" + id, null);

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but still not working i got the passid with the use of intent to get the string.valueof(id) then i use getintent to get the value of id and equate it to textview passid

Comment: you are getting wrong row id because list view position starts with 0(zero) but check your db i think in db its starting from 1,so you have to pass (id+1) in OnclickListner.

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you please explain more on how can pass id +1 in onclickListener THANK YOUU!

Comment: how are you getting 'passid' ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HEY GUYSSSS THANK YOU FOR ANSWERING I APPRECIATE YOU ALL , I JUST SUDDENLY GOT THE ANSWER WICH IS I JUST ADD 1 TO THE STRING.VALUEOF(ID) AND IT JUST WORKED OUT THANKS YOU GUYSSS!

//here is my code

intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA1 , String.valueOf(id + 1));
                startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 'passid' .

put 'passid' in your HashMap while fetching from database and then retrieve.

Comment: hi ithink my code is wrong here is where i get my passid   //mainactivity intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA1 , String.valueOf(id));              //mainactivity2 passid = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_EXTRA1);
        passidtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        passidtext.setText("ID:   " + passid + "");